Should I not have answered "Lego Friends Houses"?
The question Lego Friends Houses was closed as "Primarily opinion-based". I had already made a stab at answering it and have received 3 upvotes so far for that. Should I have just left the question, or flagged it? (I cannot yet close-vote here).
My motivation in answering it:

This site needs questions and answers and I thought I could help the OP out
The OP seemed to suffer from a severe case of "only building what the instructions say" and "not mixing themes" and I wanted to suggest a way out of that, at least partly.

A good portion of Lego questions are open-ended or opinion-based. Is there a guideline for when it goes too far?

The question has been reworded by jncraton in such a way that it is now a valid question:

Is there a way to buy LEGO houses without minifigs?

I have changed the title and reopened the question. Despite the change in title, your answer still remains relevant and I fully support you for answering.
Questions based almost entirely on opinions rather than facts/references will be closed, if a user is able to reword the contents of a question to be more suitable (in such a way that does not completely change the context) then users can either vote to 'reopen' or flag the question for moderator attention.


A good portion of Lego questions are open-ended or opinion-based. Is
  there a guideline for when it goes too far?

I cannot say for sure where exactly the line is drawn. I think the phrasing of a question, can make a lot of difference. 
A question titled 'Why are there so many LEGO Friends minifigs, but barely any houses?' can only truly be answered by either an employee from the LEGO company or an existing reference. Any other answer is speculative.
If the question is titled 'Is there a way to buy LEGO houses without minifigs?', anyone with experience or knowledge is able to answer and the answer actually solves a problem.
I don't expect everyone to agree with the examples given, it is after all my interpretation. I'd like to know what other members of the community think as well.

I think you've summed it up pretty well there :)
